# How to use WordPress' WTI Like Post in Android?

Tags: java, android, ajax, wordpress

First things first, I have a plug-in in my WordPress website called "WTI Like Post" which is a thumbs up plugin for voting posts...

Here's a preview from its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/MaineLearning/MaineLearning/tree/master/wp-content/plugins/wti-like-post):

[image: WTI Like Post preview]

If you click on these thumbs, an ajax link will fire up and vote the post, then it redirects back to the post page again. That ajax link is something like this:

http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wti_like_post_process_vote&task=like&post_id=108&nonce=0d8d1f993f

Now, I want to use these links manually! Meaning that I want to vote a post by copy and pasting that link in a new tab (And not by clicking on buttons). The problem is that when I paste the link myself, my browser returns an error:
"The page isn't redirecting properly".

I'm making an Android app for my website, and the only way I can think to vote a post, is that link.

How can I use it manually? And more importantly, how can I use it with Android's HttpURLConnection?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [JavaScript source](https://github.com/MaineLearning/MaineLearning/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/wti-like-post/js/wti_like_post.js) it would seem the Ajax link should be `http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/wti-like-post/wti_like.php`, with a POST body of `action=wti_like_post_process_vote&task=like&post_id=108&nonce=0d8d1f993f`. Thus, on Android, using the [example code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206094/1270789), this should work:

```
String urlParameters  = "action=wti_like_post_process_vote&task=like&post_id=108";
byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
int    postDataLength = postData.length;
String request        = "http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/wti-like-post/wti_like.php";
URL    url            = new URL( request );
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
conn.setUseCaches( false );
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
   wr.write( postData );
}
```

Note that the nonce is not necessary on Android as `setUseCaches(false)` will ensure that the link is followed afresh every time.

Comment: Actually, nonce is a way for the plug-in to know that user already voted or not! 

Another thing: Do I have to put two "/" after the domain name?

Comment: Oops, the `//` was my mistake! However, the nonce does not seem to be used in [wti_like.php](https://github.com/MaineLearning/MaineLearning/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/wti-like-post/wti_like.php), so I assumed it was merely to prevent caching. Multiple vote attempts are detected using [post ID and IP address](https://github.com/MaineLearning/MaineLearning/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/wti-like-post/wti_like_post.php#L768).

Comment: Alright, I wanted to use this code, but it required API 19 for that try in the end! So I changed it to `DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream()); wr.write( postData );`. But it crashes on on executing that `DataOutputStream`.  --- I also used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21657510/1930153), but It also crashes on line `conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);`. :/